VS 17.11 Spell checker пропал русский язык
После обновления VS до 17.11 из Spell Checker пропал русский язык

Проверил наличие языкового пакета как в Visual Studio

так и в Windows

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вернуть проверку русского языка в студию по умолчанию (не для отдельной сборки, добавление .editorconfig к проекту - не решение).
